# What is the equivalent of EF C# ToListAsync in F#?

Tags: f#, entity-framework-6, c#-to-f#

I have the following code in C#:

```
public async Task<List<Table>> GetRows()
{
  return await db.Table.ToListAsync();
}
```

where db is an EF 6 DbContext.

How do I write the equivalent thing in F# assuming that I access the same DbContext?

I came up with this code but I am stuck:

```
let getRows = async {
   let q = query { 
         from r in db.Table
             select r
         }
   q |> Seq.map(fun row -> ...) // <-- Here I might want to do some custom function
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no problem in using `.ToListAsync()` in F#. I assume that the point of your confusion is to make C# `await` play nicely with F# `async`.

In this case, you should use `Async.AwaitTask`
Here's a code

```
async {
    let! q = db.Table.ToListAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask //here you have a C# list
}
```

Comment: You are right. On the C# side how to I call this F# function with await? I should have re-phrased my question differently (it was late last night). I am going to accept your answer for now.

Comment: I guess if you want to call it from C# side with `await` then there's no need to wrap it into `async`

Comment: [TaskBuilder.fs](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) has helped me when writing asynchronous F# code that is only ever intended to be used from a C#/VB app.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use [TaskBuilder.fs](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs), if most of what I'm doing is going to be using c# tasks. I find this preferable to converting back and forth between Async and Task, but it depends on the apis being used.

**add from Nuget**

```sh
dotnet add package TaskBuilder.fs --version 2.1.0
```

**open and use task**

```ml
open FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2

task {
    let! q = db.Table.ToListAsync()
}
```